# django-guardian and django-rest-framework

Tags: permissions, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

I would like to manage my objects permission using django-guardian in a restful project (using django-rest-framework).

What I would like :

- Allow the connected user to create an object only if he have the
  "add_modelname" permission.
- When the connected user create an object, set the "delete_modelname"
  and "change_modelname" permission.
- Allow the connected user to edit an object only if he have the
  "change_modelobject" permission.
- Allow the connected user to delete an object only if he have the
  "delete_modelobject" permission.

I'm trying to manage thoses cases with this code :

view.py

```
class ModelNameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.

    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = ModelName.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelNameSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, ModelNamePermission)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        assign_perm("change_modelname", request.user, self)
        assign_perm("delete_modelname", request.user, self)
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

permissions.py

```
class ModelNamePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in ['GET']:
            return request.user.has_perm('view_modelname')        
        if request.method in ['POST']:
            return request.user.has_perm('add_modelname')
        if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return request.user.has_perm('change_modelname')
        if request.method in ['DELETE']:
            return request.user.has_perm('delete_modelname')
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):         
        if request.method in ['GET']:
            return request.user.has_perm('view_modelname', obj)        
        if request.method in ['POST']:
            return request.user.has_perm('add_modelname', obj)
        if request.method in ['PUT', 'PATCH']:
            return request.user.has_perm('change_modelname', obj)
        if request.method in ['DELETE']:
            return request.user.has_perm('delete_modelname', obj)
        return False
```

The first problem I encounter is that I have an error in this line :

```
assign_perm("change_modelname", request.user, self)
```

error :

```
error: 'ModelNameViewSet' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

And I think that the rest of the code will not works but at least you can see what I want to do.

I haven't seen any example with thoses specifics cases.

Edit :
Another thing is that this code :

```
request.user.has_perm('view_coachingrequest')
```

allways returns true. But I've never set this permission to my user (only tried with admin user, maybe that's why).

Comment: I'd like to do the exact same thing. Have you done it ?

Answer (score 2):

The `create` method of a viewset will return you a freshly created model instance. You are trying to assign the permission to the viewset object itself. The code for your `create` method should be as follows:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    assign_perm("change_modelname", request.user, instance)
    assign_perm("delete_modelname", request.user, instance)
    return instance
```

This will create the model instance and then assign your desired permissions to it before returning it.

Comment: The create method in a DRF viewset returns a response object, not an instance of the model. Code here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a81e60ff390b9b6788b2cac24a01ee4dd2dcffd2/rest_framework/mixins.py#L14

Are you thinking about the create method in a serializer?

Comment: Actually it can be done either in the serializer or in the perform_create() method on the viewset (the latter shown by answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230236/set-object-level-permission-with-django-rest-framework ). So the choice is yours as to where to keep that code. For me, I think I'd do it in the serializer (which might allow you to write cleaner error handling code, having the object creation in the same place as permissions assignment)