# Set object-level permission with django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

Trying to manage django-guardian object-level permissions with django-rest-framework the most cleanly and canon possible.

I want to assign a read permission (module.view_object) of an object to to the user making the request when performing a POST.

My class-based view:

```
class ObjectList(ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Object.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ObjectSerializer
  filter_backends = (DjangoObjectPermissionsFilter,)
  # MyObjectPermissions inherit from DjangoObjectPermissions and just 
  # add the 'view_model' permission
  permission_classes = (MyObjectPermissions,)

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

As described in the [django-rest-framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users), I've overloaded `perform_create` in order to pass the user to the serializer.

But how do I assign the permission (using guardian.shortcuts.assign_perm) in the serializer. Is there no other way but to override the `save` method to assign the permission manually? Isn't there some kind of standard mechanism to manage a common behavior as this one?

Comment: You could assign the permission in the perform_create(). `serializer.save()` method returns the instance that was saved, you know

Comment: I would accept you answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the permission in the `perform_create()` method of the `ViewSet`.